# Unable to run artisan using eloquent and unable to create a new record in my table

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I'm using eloquent without laravel installed.  I'm having trouble finding simple tutorials for eloquent that I can understand or that give me instructions that actually work.  My installation of Eloquent works for selecting records, enterring data in a field and more, but I am having some problems.  I am trying to add a new record to my database.  The one I found wants me to use "DB::' but it seems that I need to use artisan from the terminal to set that up.

When I run artisan from the terminal I get 'Could not open input file: artisan'.

I have read the admonition that this means I need to be in the root folder and that will solve my problem.  I am there. I'm able to use eloquent from that folder.  It is where I installed composer and eloquent.  I also read that the Artisan.php file may not have the right permissions.  I tried using chmod on it and was refused.  I should think that when composer installed eloquent it would have given it the right permissions but I tried anyway.

When I tried another route I got a mass assignment error and am aware of security issues related to mass assignment, but when creating a new record, I do need to fill in the fields of the new record.  I don't understand enough to know what the mass assignment error is telling me to do.

Here's what I tried:

```
Artists::insert(array(
    'fname' => 'Harry',
    'lname' => 'Potter',
    'tio' => 'yes',
    'preview' => 'yes',
    'telephone' => '510-717-1776'
));
```

Here's the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException: Add [fname] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [Artists]. in /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php:354 Stack trace: #0 /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(174): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fill(Array) #1 /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(404): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__construct(Array) #2 /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1208): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newInstance(Array) #3 /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php(776): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->newModelInstance(Array) #4 /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->create(Array) #5 in /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 354
```

The name of the table is artists and I did create a model for the table.  It works in other contexts. I guessed at "insert".  I also tried "create" which fell flat on its face. I'm finding eloquent quite difficult to use and quite difficult to get simple information about how to to the simple CRUD operations that I need to use it for.

Comment: You can't follow tutorials and ignore what they want to teach you. If file `artisan` does not exist, how do you expect `php artisan` to work? You get `artisan` file with Laravel, and no - you can't use it without laravel, it's just a file that bootstraps entire framework from command line. As for your problem with creating records, the error tells you - `add fname to $fillable property`. You have to **read**, 100 times if needed. It means to open your model file, find or create `protected $fillable = ['fname'];` and that's it. Add the rest of the fields there, you solved your create issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I did check and Artisan.php does exist.  It can be used without laravel according to the instructions I just used to install eloquent.  In fact after telling me how to install it, which I did, it told me to invoke artisan from the command line.  I did not know how to "add name to $fillable property".  You explanations clear and I will try it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: So I did what you suggested and got the following error:  'Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Artists::$fillable in /Users/studio-kenoli/Sites/BannerProject/as/models/Artists.php on line 11'. Used your exact syntax in the model file.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Unless you show the code, no one can do anything. From what you posted, it appears you have `protected $fillable` twice. This tells me you're new to PHP completely and are basically guessing what to do.

Comment: I'm not new to php, though I am completely new to eloquent.  Here is the code that I applied per your suggestion:use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Artists extends Eloquent { 
 
 public $timestamps = false; 

    protected $fillable = [
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'telephone'
    ];
}

Comment: Ok, could you show how you bootstrapped eloquent in that case? The error is indeed odd, I have used it standalone and please don't get me wrong but many people ask for help and usually it's a small error in the code, which they never include so we're doomed to guessing what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find out how to use artisan, but I was able to find a work around using direct eloquent commands.

Thanks for the help offered.

--Kenoli